# Using js to show elements, initial state hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a real beginner at java script and css, and I'm way out of my depth here.

I'm trying to make an element hidden to start with and appear on the click of a button (and then disappear on the click of another button.

I have this code in the head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("h5").hide(1000);
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $("h5").show(1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

and this code on the page:

```
<h5>This is a paragraph.</h5>


<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>
```

This works great BUT the initial state is showing, not hidden which I want. Can anyone help me please, and pretty please can you explain any changes in beginner's terms.

Answer (score 3):

Hide it using CSS.

```
h5 { 
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: Soooooo simple - thanks a great deal, works perfectly!